# mongodb ,агрегация, два одинаковых $match . Зачем?

Tags: mongodb

Опять вопросы по этому mongodb .Книгу листаю новую 2020 выпуска на русском но не важно - смысл в том что вряд ли смогу привести понятно в отрыве от контекста этого раздела и самого примера иначе кратко не получится.Ну а вдруг кто подскажет мало ли. Глава про агрегацию и вот такой запрос там

```
db.companies.aggregate([
    { $match: { "funding_rounds.investments.financial_org.permalink": "greylock" } },
    { $project: {
                _id: 0,
                name: 1,
                founded_year: 1,
                rounds: { $filter: {
                                    input: "$funding_rounds",
                                    as: "round",
                                    cond: { $gte: ["$$round.raised_amount", 100000000 ] }
                                    }
                        }
                } 
    },
{ $match: { "rounds.investments.financial_org.permalink": "greylock" } },
]).pretty()
```

Я не врублюсь зачем тут два одинаковых $match ? Первый сделал свою работу  - зачем второй ??

Answer (score 1):

Затем что второй не такой как первый. Они не одинаковые.

```
{$match: {"funding_rounds.investments.financial_org.permalink": "greylock"}}
{$match: {        "rounds.investments.financial_org.permalink": "greylock" }}
```

### Пример.

Есть коллекция, в которой данные по людям и животным. У тех и у других есть поля, по которым можно их сравнить, например по количеству ушей, глаз ... или по среде обитания (домашние, дикие).

Вот такие фильтры поиска:

1. `$match : {"human.antropometria.eyes_numbers": 2}`
2. `$match : {"animal.antropometria.eyes_numbers": 2}`

Найдут разные результаты!
Например вот такие:

```
$match : {"human.antropometria.eyes_numbers": 2} :

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5815f4e735ee883c37ac8b4d"),
  "human": {
    "name": "qq_qq",
    "age": "18",
    "antropometria": {
      "hand_length": "95",
      "belly_diameter": "120",
      "body_length": "175",
      "eyes_numbers": "2",
      "know_mongo": "True"
    }
  }
}


$match : {"animal.antropometria.eyes_numbers": 2}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5815f4e735ee883c37ac8b7с")
  "animal": {
    "nick": "Murzik",
    "age": "2",
    "antropometria": {
      "paws_numbers": "4",
      "eyes_numbers": "2",
      "can_self_studiing": "",
      "know_mongo": "False"
    }
  }
}
```

Хотя на первый взгляд вроде все очень одинаковое.
В твоем случае funding_rounds и rounds - тоже поиск по разным полям документов.

Comment: Я не пойму разве это не одно и тоже  ? Там в inpute так и записано что они одно и тоже ..  Ну я понимаю так . А если чуть подробней то мы сузили колекцию документов первым матчем вроде все понятно. Далее проекция - сузили по другому критерию . Эта проекция идет на вход второму матчу .. и он делает тоже что и первый .. не андерстентд я совсем )

Comment: Это разные поля.